# Reference Enum on Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, enum

Is there any way to reference a Enum in a Visualforce page? Either for comparison or display?

Something like

```
<div>
    {!MyEnum.Status1}
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not without `Apex`, I believe. You'd need to add it as a property to your controller/extension:

```
public MyEnum enumInstance { get { return MyEnum.Status1; } }
```

Then you can reference it normally:

```
<apex:outputText value="{!enumInstance}" />
```

Comment: That. Is. Crazy! It's public, yet you have to create a get property for each value in the Enum!. SF is great, but things like this are so frustrating, and needless